# ts-loader with sass-loader & ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

This topic could be considered as a continuation of my previous [question related to webpack & ts-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142521/ts-loader-css-loader-not-being-able-to-import-resolve-file)

Now I am trying to understand how to use `sass-loader` with `ts-loader` and  `ExtractTextPlugin`. After hours of digging it seems that `ExtractTextPlugin` is parsing node_modules and hence fails.

In the code example below you can see the commented part *(the old style loader part)* and new one which I'm trying to make work with guidance from `sass-loader` docs.

Currently I am stuck on this *(and dozens of other similar parsing issues from node_modules)*:
[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"); // <-- as soon as this is imported, the build fails

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});


module.exports = env => {
    return {
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
        entry: "./src/index.tsx",
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "/public"),
            filename: "build/app.js"
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".scss"],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules"),
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules"),
                    use: extractSass.extract({
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: "style-loader",
                                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules")},
                            {
                                loader: "css-loader",
                                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules")},
                            {
                                loader: "sass-loader",
                                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "/node_modules"),
                                options: {
                                    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "/src")],
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                    }),
                }
                // {
                //     test: /\.scss$/,
                //     loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' 
                // }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            extractSass,
        ]
    }
}
```

**N.B.** Without `ExtractTextPlugin` I get an empty object when importing `.scss` into a `.tsx` file. So if you can help me solve also this issue, I would be glad *(and able to continue coding)* :)

`import * as styles from "./Main.scss"; // <-- styles is {/* empty object */}`